# Startup key combinations don't work after disk swap, cannot boot into live installation media

Tags: bootcamp, startup, dual-boot, efi

I recently replaced my old iMac's HDD with an SSD. The SSD had a Linux distribution installed in it, but I didn't bother formatting it because I knew it would be formatted during OS installation.

I think that was a mistake, because I am now unable to get my iMac to boot into my live Linux installation USB. It keeps booting into the Linux distribution that was already in the SSD into a CLI-only "emergency mode" no matter what. None of the [Mac startup key combinations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) seem to work.

Here is the output of `efibootmgr -v` in the Linux distribution it keeps booting to:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
BootOrder: FFFF
Boot0080* Mac 05 X
008,0×64028,0×25294648)
PciRoot (8x0) /Pci (Bx1f,8x2)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,GPT,00087fca-363-0000-1859-008022128
BootFFFF*
PciRoot (0x0) /Pci (Ox1a, Ox1)/USB(1,0) /HD(1 , MBR, Bx0, 8x3f ,8xfc7fb9) /File (\boot.efi)
```

Reordering or deleting the entries didn't seem to fix the issue.

How do I recover from this mistake, preferably without opening the iMac again to access the SSD?

Comment: Holding down the option key at startup should at least  get you to the Mac Startup Manager. What model/year is your Mac?

Comment: @DavidAnderson it doesn’t. None of the Mac startup key combinations work. It’s a 2009 20” iMac.

Comment: @DavidAnderson should I delete the EFI partition to reboot into Mac Startup Manager?

Comment: You could try that, but I do not know if that would work. Are you using the keyboard that came with the Mac? I have certain Windows keyboards that when used with my 2007 iMac, some of the startup key combinations do not work.